# How to use Gesture Recognition Toolkit (GRT) using its interface to train (HMM model) and test from datasets which have already been created?

Tags: machine-learning, toolkit, gesture-recognition, hidden-markov-models, gmm

I am currently working on a project-Air Writing using inertial sensors. Based on the 6-DOF (Degrees Of Freedom), accelerometer and gyroscope values received from the sensor placed on the finger, the system should identify the gesture made using the finger- basically characters ('a' to 'z'). I came across the **[Gesture Recognition Toolkit (GRT)](http://nickgillian.com/grt/index.html)** which has a new interface in one of its recent updates. **So, can someone help me in explaining as to how to train (using HMM) and test the output using the toolkit in its new interface**? I'm new to machine learning, hence I don't exactly understand as to where to begin. This toolkit seems to be a short-path toward what I intend to achieve as the output that is identify characters written on air. I have created a database of the inertial sensor values for characters 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd'. Now I want to know how to proceed through the Machine Learning part using this toolkit. **Can anyone help me?**